# How to insert data to two tables related through a foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to insert data to two tables related to each other through Foreign Key.  Table dbo.Ansatte has a primary key called ansatID and table dbo.Login_data has a primary key called brugerID and foreign key AnsatID, which reference to primary key ansatID in table dbo.Ansatte. The primary key in both tables are inserted incrementally when the query s running.The problem is, that after running the query, foreign key AnsatID in table dbo.Login_data is still NULL despite the fact that foreign key AnsatID reference to primary key called ansatID in table dbo.Ansatte.

I have tried to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON (in ms sql server management studio), but it doesn't help as I still get error message that IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Here is the code:

```
try
                {
                    String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                    myconnection.Open();

                    SqlCommand AddWorkerCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
                    AddWorkerCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Ansatte ([Navn], [Efternavn], [Adresse], [Postnummer], [Bynavn], [Email], [Mobilnr]) VALUES ( @Navn, @Efternavn, @Adresse, @Postnummer, @Bynavn, @Email, @Mobilnr)";

                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", textBox1.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efternavn", textBox2.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", textBox3.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postnummer", textBox4.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bynavn", textBox5.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox6.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilnr", textBox7.Text);
                    AddWorkerCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlCommand AddUserCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
                    AddUserCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Login_data ([Brugernavn], [Adgangskode], [Brugertype]) VALUES ( @Brugernavn, @Adgangskode, @Brugertype)";

                    AddUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brugernavn", textBox10.Text);
                    AddUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adgangskode", textBox9.Text);
                    AddUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brugertype", textBox8.Text);
                    AddUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    myconnection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Desired result is that foreign key AnsatID in table dbo.Login_data has the same value as primary key ansatID in table dbo.Ansatte. Actual result shown on the picture below. Actual result is, that foreign key AnsatID in table dbo.Login_data is still NULL after running the above code, like on the picture:

[image]

Comment: side note - do not use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scope_identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the last used identity value in the same scope. So changing your code to

```
...
AddUserCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Login_data ([ansatID], [Brugernavn], [Adgangskode], [Brugertype]) VALUES (scope_identity(), @Brugernavn, @Adgangskode, @Brugertype)";
...
```

should do what you want.

I also recommend not to use `AddWithValue()` which needs to guess the data type and sometimes can be horribly wrong. Use [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) explicitly giving the data type. For example

```
...
AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.Add("@Navn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = textBox1.Text;
...
```

if `Navn` is an `nvarchar(64)` on the database.

Comment: Best to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in case triggers exist.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Good catch! You're right, `scope_identity()` is the safer bet.

Comment: It doesn't work with SCOPE_IDENTITY()...but it works with @@IDENTITY, so I'm happy about it at least :)) and now I also use Add() instead AddWithValue() and it all works...thank you :)